# how can i listing component nestedly?

Tags: reactjs, rendering, nested-lists

```
[
  {
    "id": 0.5256669517010202,
    "color": false,
    "selected": false,
    "name": "",
    "type": "",
    "label": "",
    "fieldName": "",
    "required": "",
    "validation": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 0.5901705709044824,
    "color": false,
    "selected": false,
    "type": [
      {
        "id": 0.30332161644408817,
        "color": true,
        "selected": false,
        "name": "",
        "type": "",
        "label": "",
        "fieldName": "",
        "required": "",
        "validation": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 0.5423422175390649,
        "color": true,
        "selected": false,
        "name": "",
        "type": "",
        "label": "",
        "fieldName": "",
        "required": "",
        "validation": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 0.959208393000617,
        "color": true,
        "selected": false,
        "name": "",
        "type": "",
        "label": "",
        "fieldName": "",
        "required": "",
        "validation": ""
      }
    ],
    "label": "",
    "fieldName": "",
    "required": "",
    "validation": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 0.5933110602496239,
    "color": false,
    "selected": false,
    "type": "",
    "label": "",
    "fieldName": "",
    "required": "",
    "validation": ""
  }
]
```

Comment: Are you just needing to map the outer array, and occasionally render the nested `type` array? What have you tried on your own already? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use Map method

```
const data = [
  {
    "id": 0.5256669517010202,
    "color": false,
    "selected": false,
    "name": "",
    "type": "",
    "label": "",
    "fieldName": "",
    "required": "",
    "validation": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 0.5901705709044824,
    "color": false,
    "selected": false,
    "type": [
      {
        "id": 0.30332161644408817,
        "color": true,
        "selected": false,
        "name": "",
        "type": "",
        "label": "",
        "fieldName": "",
        "required": "",
        "validation": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 0.5423422175390649,
        "color": true,
        "selected": false,
        "name": "",
        "type": "",
        "label": "",
        "fieldName": "",
        "required": "",
        "validation": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 0.959208393000617,
        "color": true,
        "selected": false,
        "name": "",
        "type": "",
        "label": "",
        "fieldName": "",
        "required": "",
        "validation": ""
      }
    ],
    "label": "",
    "fieldName": "",
    "required": "",
    "validation": ""
  },
  {
    "id": 0.5933110602496239,
    "color": false,
    "selected": false,
    "type": "",
    "label": "",
    "fieldName": "",
    "required": "",
    "validation": ""
  }
]

data.map((item) => item.id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Try!
You should declared attribute type as Array always!

```
data.map(Item => (
  Item.type.map(Item => ())
))
```

Answer (score 0):

the `map` method is suitable here. For example you have your all data within state or another variable, well you can map throw it:

```
 <div>
    {yourData?.length && yourData.map(item => {
       return(
           <span>{item.id}</span>
           ...
          <div>{item.type.map(typeItem => {
             return(
                <span>{typeItem.id}</span>
                ...
             )
           })
        )})}
 </div>
```